# The page was not displayed because the request entity is too large. in .Net Core 2.1

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.1

I am Facing the problems while Uploading the files to the server through API
When I try to upload the Image size 8 Mb to server From Postman. For the first time, I try to upload it shows "The page was not displayed because the request entity is too large". But the strange thing is "When I upload the small size image like 300 Kb it uploads and tries to upload the next image like 8 MB it uploads and After 3 or 5 minutes  im getting same error.

My Upload code

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class UploadImageController : Controller
{
    private IHostingEnvironment _environment;
    public UploadImageController(IHostingEnvironment environment)
    {
        _environment = environment;
    }
    internal void IsExists(string filepath)
    {
        if (!Directory.Exists(_environment.WebRootPath + "\\media"))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(_environment.WebRootPath + "\\media");
        }
        if (!Directory.Exists(_environment.WebRootPath + "\\media\\" + filepath))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(_environment.WebRootPath + "\\media\\" + filepath);
        }
    }
    internal string GetNewFileName(string filenamestart, string fullname)
    {
        Char delimiter = '.';
        string fileExtension;
        string strFileName = string.Empty;
        strFileName = DateTime.Now.ToString().
            Replace(" ", string.Empty).
            Replace("/", "-").Replace(":", "-");
        fileExtension = fullname.Split(delimiter).Last();
        Random ran = new Random();
        strFileName = $"{ filenamestart}_{ran.Next(0, 100)}_{strFileName}.{fileExtension}";
        return strFileName;
    }
    private bool IsValidExtension(IFormFile filename)
    {
        bool isValid = false;
        Char delimiter = '.';
        string fileExtension;
        string[] imgTypes = new string[] { "png", "jpg", "gif", "jpeg" };
        fileExtension = filename.FileName.Split(delimiter).Last();
        // fileExtension = substrings[substrings.Length - 1].ToString();
        int fileType = 0;
        if (imgTypes.Contains(fileExtension.ToLower()))
        {
            fileType = 1;
        }

        switch (fileType)
        {
            case 1:
                if (imgTypes.Contains(fileExtension.ToLower()))
                {
                    isValid = true;
                }
                break;
            default:
                isValid = false;
                break;
        }
        return isValid;
    }
    [HttpPost]
    // GET: api/<controller>
    [Route("UploadapiImage")]
    [RequestFormLimits(MultipartBodyLengthLimit = 209715200)]
    [RequestSizeLimit(209715200)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> UploadapiImage()
    {
        try
        {

            var Files=Request.Form.Files;
            if (Files.Count == 0)
            {
                return Ok(Json(""));
            }
            IsExists("Mobile");
            //var file = Convert.FromBase64String(objUploadModel.File);
            string uploads = _environment.WebRootPath + "\\media\\Mobile";
            int i = 0;
            string[] strFileNames = new string[Files.Count];
            foreach (var file in Files)
            {
                if (IsValidExtension(file))
                {
                    string imagename = GetNewFileName("Mobile", Files[i].FileName);
                    string fullpath = uploads + "\\" + imagename;
                    using (FileStream fileStream = System.IO.File.Create(fullpath))
                    {
                        await Task.Run(() => Files[i].CopyToAsync(fileStream));
                        fileStream.Flush();
                        fileStream.Close();
                    }

                    strFileNames[i] = "\\media\\Mobile\\" + imagename;
                }
                else
                {
                    strFileNames[i] = "";
                }
                i++;
            }
            return Ok(strFileNames);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Ok("Exception from Api");
        }

    }
}
```

In Startup.cs

```
services.Configure<FormOptions>(x =>
        {
            x.ValueLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
            x.MultipartHeadersLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
            x.MultipartBodyLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
        });
```

In Web Config.

```
<requestFiltering>

    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" />  

  </requestFiltering>
```

I try to keep logs in server and IIS I didn't find any information.
In IIS logs it writes

```
#Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 10.0
```

## Version: 1.0

## Date: 2019-11-10 05:59:05

## Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) cs(Referer) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status time-taken

2019-11-10 05:59:05 10.0.0.4 POST /api/UploadImage/UploadapiImage - 443 - 27.34.104.230 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/78.0.3904.97+Safari/537.36 - 413 0 0 1636

My IIS version in sever is show on Image.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Why I am getting the problem ("The page was not displayed because the request entity is too large") 
in my website, **SSL Setting** is **Accept**
 I just set it to **Ignore** then it works.

[image]